# I don't want to have the error when I drop a table although the table doesn't exist

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sqlplus

I am using Oracle 12c and I am not interesting to have an error while droping my table 'CONTINENT' in case it doesn't exist.

I did this

```
set echo on

set serveroutput on
alter session set current_schema=WORK_ODI;
set verify off
set pause off
--
WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE  

drop table  CONTINENT;

COMMIT;

EXIT;
```

but it coudn't skipe the error when the table doesn't exist, how can I fix this problem please

Comment: Cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35128900/330315

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been crossposted to stack overflow and has an upvoted answer and several comments there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Oracle does not have anything like for example `IF EXISTS` in MySQL. You can do the above in a PL/SQL block, catch the exception, then do nothing with it.

```
begin
  execute immediate 'drop table continent';
  exception when others then null;
end;
/
```

Comment: `exception when others then null;` is not the best solution. You can get other exception e.g. `insufficient privileges` which may cause unexpected results. Better use `exception when others then IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN NULL; END IF;`